# Dart - Create a class to extend List<Todo> functions

Tags: class, dart

I am creating a Flutter application and I have a `List<Todo>`.
I want to create a class with added widget functionality on top of the normal list functions.

I tried extending a List, but I get a "Missing concrete implementation of iterable" of 61 functions. I don't want to create 61 implementations of just invoking the "super" method, just to add one function.

```dart
class TodoList extends List<Todo>{

  ListView asListView(){
    return ListView(
    children: this.map((Todo todo){
        return todo.asListTile();
    }).toList()
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ListMixin`:

```
class TodoList implements List<Todo> with ListMixin<Todo> {
...
```

Comment: You will still need to implement a number of basic operations (as documneted on the `ListMixin` class), but not all of them. The `ListMixin` class is a skeleton class with a default implementation for most operations written in terms of the smaller number of basic operations.